# Shareholders' Equity strange formula

Tags: accounting

I can understand this equity formula:

Shareholders’ Equity = Total Assets − Total Liabilities

But about this one:

SE = Share Capital + Retained Earnings - Treasury Shares

Why aren't (in the second formula) we taking into account company's **bond capital**? I mean, lot's of company's **assets** were bought through loans? Why we only take into account **share capital**? How can these two formulas possibly give the same number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why aren't (in the second formula) we taking into account company's bond capital?

Becasue bonds represent the *debt* that a company owes. If you buy a $100,000 house with an $80,000 mortgage, you only "own" $20,000 in *equity*. If you sell the house, you have to pay back the loan.

Same for a company. If it liquidates its assets, it must pay back its bonds, so whatever is left over is the *equity*.

So the total equity is the total that it's raised through share (equity) offerings, plus the total net amount it's earned over its lifetime (retained earnings), minus what it's bought back (treasury shares).  All other assets must have been bought with debt in order for the accounting equations to balance out.

Comment: Would this leave out current-year profits? I have the impression (possibly mistaken) that Retained Profits is only updated at the close/open of each financial year.

Comment: If you wanted a mid-period value then yes you would include mid-period profits.